# Implementing contains in typescript + gremlin

Tags: typescript, gremlin, graph-databases

In my javascript and gremlin implementation, I am able to use contains with no problem:

```js
const gremlin = require("gremlin");
const __ = gremlin.process.statics; 
const findByPartialProperty = async(value) => {
var result = await g
.V()
.properties()
.filter(__.contains(value)
... etc
}
```

This doesn't throw any errors, and I'm able to use this query.

However, when I try to implement in typescript:

```js
import gremlin from "gremlin"
const __:any = gremlin.process.statics;
const findByPartialProperty = async(value: string) => {
var result = await g
.V()
.properties()
.filter(__.contains(value)
... etc
}
```

If I don't assign type "any" to the statics import, I get that contains isn't a function. When I add "any" to the import, I am able to run the code, but once I am in the playground/trying to run queries, I get the same error: contains is not a function.

How do I implement gremlin contains in typescript?

Comment: Are you mentioning abount `containing` ? `TextP.containing(string) >> Does the incoming String contain the provided String?` I am not seeing anything called contains?

Answer (score 2):

TinkerPop Documentation on containing is [here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#a-note-on-predicates)

`containing` is not part of `statics` but `TextP`

```
import gremlin from "gremlin"
const textp = gremlin.process.TextP;

.filter(textp.containing(value))
```